# Compute thrust applied to ship's sails depending on sailSize, sailState and relative angle of wind

Tags: unity, c#, mathematics, linear-algebra

I'm trying to calculate the speed of a ship, depending on many factors.

- the speed of the wind
- the relative angle between the sails forward and the wind forward. transformed into `angleSpeed`
- the 'size of the sail relative to total size of all sails of that mast'
- the sail's 'state'

Simple system for the sail's 'state':

- 0 - sail is furled (packed) - not in use
- 1 - sail is unfurled and raised  - not in use but still catching wind as its unpacked
- 2 - sail is unfurled and set - in use and catching full wind.

Then the calculation of speed has to be divided by each sail, and in fact each sail calculates its own size and its `sizePercetage` out of all `sailSizesTotal`.

So basically I'm trying to.

1. check the relative angle of mast/wind
2. check state of sail under that mast
3. calculate speed of that sail based on the sail's `sizePercentage`, the `relativeAngle` and the sail's state
4. all those values are between 0.000f and 1.000f
5. calculate mast speed (all sails under that mast)
6. calculate ship speed (all masts)

The easiest way to show what I'm trying to achieve is by looking at the code below I think:

```
    float mizzenMastAngle = mizzenMast.localEulerAngles.y;

    float relMizzenToWindAngle = GetRelativeAngle(mizzenMastAngle, windAngle);

    float mizzenMastAngleSpeed = WindManager.instance.GetSpeedFromWindAngle(relMizzenToWindAngle);

    float mizzenMastSpeed = 0f;
    foreach (SailControl sailControl in mizzenMastSails)
    {
        float sailSizePercentage = sailControl.GetSail().sizePercentage;

        float sailStateMultiplier = 0.1f;
        switch (sailControl.GetSail().state)
        {
            case 0:
                sailStateMultiplier = 0.1f;
                break;
            case 1:
                sailStateMultiplier = 0.25f;    //Debug values, change later to smaller
                break;
            case 2:
                sailStateMultiplier = 1f;
                break;
        }
        float thisSailSpeed = sailSizePercentage * sailStateMultiplier * mizzenMastAngleSpeed; // Range: 0.0f - 1.0f for these variables.
        mizzenMastSpeed += thisSailSpeed;

    }
    float mainMastAngle = mainMast.localEulerAngles.y;
    float foreMastAngle = foreMast.localEulerAngles.y;

...
ship.speed = mizzenMastSpeed + mainMastSpeed + foreMastSpeed;
```

Specifically this line is what I need help with as it doesn't work as intended:

```
float thisSailSpeed = sailSizePercentage * sailStateMultiplier * mizzenMastAngleSpeed; // Range: 0.0f - 1.0f for these variables.
```

I think here `mizzenMastSpeed` should have a max of 1?

Basically if all mizzen sails are being used it should be `maxspeed` for `mizzenmastSpeed`.

If only half the sails are being used, but some are furled and some are set, all these calculations should return the correct speed for that mast, then for the other masts, based on what states, angle and percentage of total is being used.

Then I want to apply all those speeds together to the ship in a correct way.

So if I take down a single sail on 1 mast it should decrease the overall speed of the ship according to the size of that sail, the angle of the wind it was catching and its state.

I hope someone can help me with this.

Code for getting total size and individual size of sails:

```
    int totalsize = 0;
    foreach (SailControl sailC in mizzenMastSails)
    {
        int size = sailC.GetSail().size;
        totalsize += size;
    }

    float sizePercentage = 0;
    float totalPercentage = 0;
    foreach (SailControl sailC in mizzenMastSails)
    {
        int size = sailC.GetSail().size;
        sizePercentage = (((float)size) / totalsize); // Range 0f - 1f
        sailC.SetSizePercentage(sizePercentage);
        totalPercentage += sizePercentage;
    }
```

EDIT:

My progress so far:

```
    float thisSailSpeed = sailSize * sailStateMultiplier;
    mizzenMastSpeed += thisSailSpeed;
    }
    // Multiply by value based on relative wind angle between mast and wind.
    mizzenMastSpeed *= mizzenMastAngleSpeed;

    totalSpeed = mizzenMastSpeed + mainMastSpeed + foreMastSpeed + staysSpeed;
    totalSpeed *= windSpeed;
    totalSpeed *= speedMax;
```

Comment: For all that code, there is one thing I do not get/ see. It seems it does not matter how big your sails are. Yes, you calculate each sail by percentage, but there is nothing in your math that would make a ship with a tiny sail slower than a 5 mast.

Comment: Yes that is precisely right, i will just use this to get a value from 0 to 1 and multiply an overal speed for each ship based on its type.(and sails amount/weight/etc)
And if a ship has 1 mast it will just ignore the other non existing masts with this code I think.

Comment: Would it be simpler to calculate the overall actual force provided by the wind instead (that's equivalent to air drag, roughly)? It seems to me that with the right formula, you just pass in the size of the sail set, and sum the values for all the masts, and you get the value. You then use it with the friction between the ship and the water (which imply how much the ship is loaded) to compute the speed.

Comment: That seems like a really cool idea, could you expand on it in an answer? I will edit my question with some progress I have made in the meantime. I now multiply sailState and sailSize, add up that value for each sail, and in the end multiply all those added up values with the windAngleSpeedFactor, this leaves me with a 0 to 1 value that actually represents how much speed the ship should be getting taking into account sailsize, state and angle. Furthermore I then multiply that final value with the actual windSpeed, and then multiply again with shipType speed to give every type a unique speed.